# Is file cache flushed automatically after time?

Tags: files, cache

Let's say I copy a file using **cp** and the proccess returns immedietly because the file was written to cache.
Then I leave the PC alone for 1 hour. Nothing special running on it.

Is the cache flushed automatically in this time?

Does it matter if the file (writing to) is a block device file, a mapper file or normal file?

Comment: Please avoid what [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/382821/355310) describes.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski did it

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the cache is flushed as soon as OS is able to do it. Second, even the least important process has a chance to do its work.

For example, even if you have a super-high priority process, which is constantly touching hard drive, then even a super-low shell operation will have a chance to remind cache that it has some data to flush.

So, the answer is no.

Comment: I think you mean "yes". See my edit... Maybe you can answer if this applies to all kind of files like block devices and mapper files ?